# Jquery Count Elements By Class Returning Wrong Numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

[image]

What i am doing is when checkbox checked i am appending id,charges and test name in hidden fields but  when i get count before adding appending new hidden fields its giving me wrong numbers, dont know why

Here is my jquery code:

```
$("input.checkBoxTests").live('change', function () {
    var charges = $('#sample-table-3').find('td.TestCharges#' + this.id).html();
    var TestName = $('#sample-table-3').find('td.TestName#' + this.id).html()
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#selectedTestsTable").find('tbody')
            .append($('<tr>')
            .attr('id', this.id)
            .attr('class', "bookedTest")
            .append($('<td>')
            .append($('#sample-table-3').find('td.TestName#' + this.id).html()

        )));
        var TestIdIndex = $("input.iHiddenTestId").length;
        var CheckingIndex = $("input.iHiddenCheck").length
        $('input.iHiddenCheck').each(function () {
            console.log("Checking id:" + $(this).id + ", value:" + $(this).val() + "count:" + CheckingIndex);
        });
        var newTestId = $("<input id='" + this.id + "' type='hidden' value='" + this.id + "' class='iHiddenTestId' name='Tests[" + TestIdIndex + "].TestId' />");
        $("form#ImgUpload").append(newTestId);
        $("form#ImgUpload").append("<input id='" + this.id + "' type='text' value='" + this.id + "' class='iHiddenCheck' name='Tests[" + CheckingIndex + "].TestId' />")
        var ChargesIndex = $("form#ImgUpload input.iHiddenCharges").length;
        var newCharges = $("<input id='" + this.id + "' type='hidden' value='" + charges + "' class='iHiddenCharges' name='Tests[" + ChargesIndex + "].Charges' />");
        $("form#ImgUpload").append(newCharges);
        var TestNameIndex = $("form#ImgUpload input.iHiddenTestName").length;
        var newTestName = $("<input id='" + this.id + "' type='hidden' value='" + TestName + "' class='iHiddenTestName' name='Tests[" + TestNameIndex + "].TestName' />");
        $("form#ImgUpload").append(newTestName);
    } else {
        $("#selectedTestsTable").find('tr#' + this.id).remove()
        $("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenTestId#' + this.id).remove();
        $("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenCharges#' + this.id).remove();
        $("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenTestName#' + this.id).remove();
    }
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<div style="max-height:490px;overflow:auto;" class="col-lg-12" id="genRequestContainer">

<form method="post" id="ImgUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax-success="SendRequestSuccess" data-ajax-failure="SendRequestFail" data-ajax-complete="SendRequestComplete" data-ajax-begin="SendRequestBegin" data-ajax="true" action="/HealthAccess/TestRequest/SendRequest?Length=11">    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="CliqPanelID">



</div>
<div id="panelTestsContainer"> 
<h3 class="header smaller lighter blue">Lab Tests</h3>


<div class="row">
<div style=" height:80%; overflow:auto;" class="col-lg-8">
<div class="table-header">
Results for Lab Tests
</div>

<div style="height:170px;padding-right: 0px !important;
padding-left: 0px !important;" class="col-lg-12">


<div role="grid" class="dataTables_wrapper" id="sample-table-3_wrapper"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="dataTables_filter" id="sample-table-3_filter"><label>Search: <input type="text" aria-controls="sample-table-3"></label></div></div></div><table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="sample-table-3" aria-describedby="sample-table-3_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row"><th class="center sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-3" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="

        : activate to sort column ascending">

        </th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-3" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="
            Test Name
        : activate to sort column ascending">
            Test Name
        </th><th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sample-table-3" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="
            Charges
        : activate to sort column ascending">
            Charges
        </th></tr>
    </thead>


<tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all"><tr class="odd">
        <td class="center ">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ace checkBoxTests" id="1668">
        <span class="lbl"></span>
        </label>
        </td>
        <td class="TestName " id="1668">B.P (                   /</td>
        <td class="TestCharges " id="1668">230</td>


    </tr><tr class="even">
        <td class="center ">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ace checkBoxTests" id="1031">
        <span class="lbl"></span>
        </label>
        </td>
        <td class="TestName " id="1031">CBC &amp; ESR Profile</td>
        <td class="TestCharges " id="1031">280</td>


    </tr><tr class="odd">
        <td class="center ">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="ace checkBoxTests" id="877">
        <span class="lbl"></span>
        </label>
        </td>
        <td class="TestName " id="877">Urine Examination (DR)</td>
        <td class="TestCharges " id="877">90</td>


    </tr></tbody></table><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="dataTables_info" id="sample-table-3_info">Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries</div></div><div class="col-sm-6"><div class="dataTables_paginate paging_bootstrap"><ul class="pagination"><li class="prev disabled"><a href="#"><i class="icon-double-angle-left"></i></a></li><li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li><li class="next disabled"><a href="#"><i class="icon-double-angle-right"></i></a></li></ul></div></div></div></div>

</div>

</div>





<div style=" height:80%; overflow:auto;" class="col-lg-4">
<div class="table-header">
Selected Tests
</div>

<div id="selectedTestsContainer" style="height:170px;padding-right: 0px !important;
padding-left: 0px !important;" class="col-lg-12">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="selectedTestsTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>

        <th>
            Test Name
        </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>






    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>






</div>





</div>
    <div id="hiddenContainer">

    <input type="hidden" name="DependentId" class="iHiddenDependent" value="1" id="1"></div>
</form>












     </div>
```

I am getting the hidden fields count of particular class by using length in jquery but its giving me wrong number i tested by appending text boxes the text boxes displayed on page three but when i get length by class it returns wrong number, i am stucked. Thanks all.

Comment: Please provide some HTML and/or a working example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why do you look for `td.TestCharges#' + this.id` instead of just `'#' + this.id`?

Comment: because i have this td with this id multiple so i need class specific selector

Comment: @Blazemonger i added my partia view as well

Answer (score 1):

Mabye you forgot to remove the Inputtag:

```
<input id="1031" type="text" value="1031" class="iHiddenCheck" name="Tests[0].TestId">
```

You can add

```
$("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenCheck#' + this.id).remove();
```

after this

```
$("#selectedTestsTable").find('tr#' + this.id).remove()
$("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenTestId#' + this.id).remove();
$("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenCharges#' + this.id).remove();
$("form#ImgUpload").find('input.iHiddenTestName#' + this.id).remove();
```